# CSS backdrop-filter changing layout/hierarchy

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I currently working on my first WordPress Theme and stumbled across something I can't wrap my head around... I habe a `<nav>` element. In the `<nav>` element is `<div class="burger">`. The `.burger` is positioned fixed on the bottom of the page. When i now add `backdrop-filter: blur(5px);` to `nav` `.burger` starts to stick to `nav` again. `bottom: 0;` now doesn't stick it to the bottom of the html but to the bottom of `nav`... what?

How it's supposed to be Positioned

[image: 1]

After toggling the backdrop-filter

[image: 2]

Html:

```
<nav>
<div class="burger">
    <div class="burger-ln" id="ln1"></div>
    <div class="burger-ln" id="ln2"></div>
    <div class="burger-ln" id="ln3"></div>
</div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    --nav-background-color: rgba(90, 68, 185, 0.4);
    --nav-background-color-dark: gray;
    --nav-text-color: white;
    --akzent-color: pink;
    --border-radius: 5px;
    --nav-padding: 5px;
    --nav-margin-bottom: calc((var(--nav-padding)) * 3);
    --nav-margin-top: 5%;
    --burger-margin-bottom: var(--nav-padding);
    --burger-margin-right: var(--nav-padding);
    --burger-hight: 100px;
    --burger-width: 100px;
    --burger-ln-high: 10px;
    --burger-padding: 25px;
}

nav {
    background-color: var(--nav-background-color);
    color: var(--nav-text-color);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: var(--nav-padding);
    margin-top: var(--nav-margin-top);
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: var(--nav-margin-bottom);
}

nav .burger {
    background-color: var(--nav-background-color);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    border-radius: var(--def-border-radius);
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-right: var(--burger-margin-right);
    margin-bottom: var(--burger-margin-bottom);
    padding: var(--burger-padding);
    width: var(--burger-width);
    height: var(--burger-hight);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    filter: drop-shadow(10px, 10px, 2px, black)
}
```

The `backdrop-filter` property shouldn't change anything in the layout, should it? Is this a Chrom bug? I am properly just missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `backdrop-filter` applies the filter to everything behind the element, and in order to do that, it might be restoring the flow of `.burger` (not sure). Now I might ask. Is it necessary for `.burger` to be inside `nav`? If its position is fixed, it no longer needs a parent for ordering the flow. I would recommend to put `.burger` outside of `nav`, being a direct child of `body`, if possible.

Comment: Thank you first of all for answering! Yes, putting `.burger` outside of `nav` would solve the Problem but it sounds a bit janky to me...? `.burger` is part of my `.nav` structure... I am just confused by backdrop-filter. There should be a way to cancle its effect in `.burger` right?